# Uniformizer of a totally ramified radical extension of local fields

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, local-field

> Let $L/K$ be a totally ramified finite radical extension of local fields of characteristic $0$, where $L = K(\sqrt[p^m] a)$ and $p$ is the characteristic of the residue field.
>   If $v_K(a)=1$, then $X^{p^m}-a$ is an Eisenstein polynomial, $[L:K]=p^m$ and $\sqrt[p^m] a $ is a uniformizer of $L$ satisfying $\mathcal O_L = \mathcal O_K[\sqrt[p^m] a ]$. But if this assumption is not given, I was not able to find a similar statement.

---

Is it possible to determine a uniformizer or a $\mathcal O_K$-generator of $\mathcal O_L$ in general?

Comment: Non-archimedian local field of characteristic $0$ means finite extension of $\Bbb{Q}_q$, thus everything is about $q$ : if $p\ne q$ with $K'=K(\zeta_{p^m}),L'=L(\zeta_{p^m})$  then $L'/K'$ is totally ramified of degree $p^k= [L:K]$ so $\pi_{L'}^{p^k} = u \pi_{K'},u\in O_{L'}^\times$ and since $u^{1/p^k}\in O_{L'}^\times$ then $\varpi_{L'} = \pi_{K'}^{1/p^k}$ is an uniformizer and $L'=K'(\pi_{K'}^{1/p^k})$. If $q=p$ it is wildly ramified which is much more complicated. In other words we care of the characteristic of the residue field not of $K$.

Comment: Thank you, but I forgot to mention that I am interested in the wildly ramified case and $p$ is the characteristic of the residue field.